# Uniform convergence on compact sets of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set, let $u:K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.

> Show that $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in K}\sup_{|y|\leq 1/n}|u(x-y)-u(x)|\rightarrow0$, for $n\rightarrow \infty$

Here is my plan:

1. Show that $x \mapsto \sup_{|y|\leq 1/n}|u(x-y)-u(x)|$ is continuous
2. Using the latter point  and the continuity of $u$, we have $x_n,y_n$ such that $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in K}\sup_{|y|\leq 1/n}|u(x-y)-u(x)|=\displaystyle \sup_{|y|\leq 1/n}|u(x_n-y)-u(x_n)|=|u(x_n-y_n)-u(x_n)|$, with $|x_n-y_n|\leq1/n$
3. Using uniform continuity, for every $\epsilon$ we have $|u(x_n-y_n)-u(x_n)|<\epsilon$ after some $n$, since $|x_n-y_n|\leq1/n$

Is everything correct? Do you have a hint on how to prove step 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use uniform directly continuity of $u$.

Fix $\epsilon >0$. There exists $\alpha >0$ such that $$\forall x,x^\prime \in K, \; |x-x^\prime| < \alpha \Rightarrow |u(x)-u(x^\prime)|< \epsilon.$$ So take $N$ such that $1/N < \alpha$. One has $$\forall n \geqslant N, \forall x \in K, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \left( |y| \leqslant 1/n \text{ and } x-y \in K \right) \Rightarrow |u(x-y)-u(x)| <\epsilon.$$ That gives you $$\sup_{x \in K} \left( \sup_{|y| \leqslant 1/n \text{ and } x-y \in K} |u(x-y)-u(x)| \right) \leqslant \epsilon$$ for all $n \geqslant N$.